# Angular router outlet automatically activating

Tags: angular

In the parent view I have a mat-button-toggle-group to switch between a grid and list layout. The grid layout uses the router-outlet to display the child-component `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, but the list layout implements the child component directly using the selector `<child-view [child]="childItem"></child-view>`.

Both gird and list html are in the same parent html file but are displayed by checking the `viewStyle` variable. When the mat-button-toggle-group button is pressed the new viewStyle is set and passed as a query param; the route is navigated back to the original parent view with no params, only query params - `this.router.navigate([this.parentName],{ queryParams: { viewStyle: this.viewStyle }});`.

So in the grid view, when you click on a child element, it activates the router link and displays information correctly. Then if you click on the list view it will deactivate the router link and switch correctly. The problem is when you click back to the grid link, the router outlet automatically activates and the last child to be selected is show in the display.

Is there a way to reset the router outlet when the viewStyle changes or are there other ways to route the page?

EDIT:
An organization (parent) has multiple repositories (child)...I want to display repos in grid and list views. When you click on a repo in the grid view it displays information on the right and adds the repo name to the url. The list view is just mat-expansion-panels, when you click on one it expands with the repository-view selector component.

**routes**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':orgName',
    component: OrganizationViewComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: ':repoName',
        component: RepositoryViewComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group (change)="viewChange($event)" [value]="viewStyle">
  <mat-button-toggle value="grid">Grid View</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="list">List View</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>

<div *ngIf="viewStyle==='grid'">
  <div class="org-grid-view-content">
    <h3>Repositories for {{orgName}}</h3>
    <span *ngFor="let repo of repos">
      <mat-card class="col-sm-1 repo-label" (click)="displayRepoView(repo)" [routerLink]="[repo.name]" [queryParams]="getQueryParams()" *ngIf="shouldShowRepo(repo)"
  [ngClass]="applyClasses(repo)">
      <!-- mat-card-information -->
      </mat-card>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="repo-view-container">
    <h3 *ngIf="currentrepo">Pull Requests for {{currentrepo.name}} repository</h3>
    <h3 *ngIf="!currentrepo">Select a repository to view pull request and status details</h3>
    <p>sort and search options</p>
    <router-outlet</router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="viewStyle==='list'">
  <div class="org-list-view-content">
    <h3>Repositories</h3>
    <span *ngFor="let repo of repos">
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <repository-view
        [repo]="repo">
        </repository-view>
      </<mat-expansion-panel>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
viewChange(event: any) {
    this.viewStyle = event.value;
    this.openRepos = [];
    this.currentrepo = null;
    this.router.navigate([this.orgName, {
      outlets: { primary: null }
    }], { queryParams: this.getQueryParams() })
  }
```

Comment: Why did you do redirect ? Maybe better solution is change only viewStyle and then check (ngIf) what should be display list or grid.

Comment: It does check with an ngIf*however, if the child view is already selected the route will be `/parentName/childName` and when you change the viewStyle, I don't want the child name to be in the URL. I want it to reset to the only show the parent view

Comment: What is the name of outlet in which you display item details ?

Comment: its the primary outlet

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.router.navigate([this.parentName, {
  outlets: {
    primary: null
  }
}], { queryParams: { viewStyle: this.viewStyle } })
```

[Angular - clearing secondary routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#clearing-secondary-routes)

Comment: It seems to not stay cleared. The router outlet is deactivated correctly when the list button is clicked, but when the router navigates and the viewStyle is 'grid', the router-outlet is automatically loaded

Comment: Does this HTML is OrganizationViewComponent template ?

Comment: Ok, I suggest to not use router to do this - remove <router-outlet>. When you click on repo in grid mode do something like you do with h3 tag if !currentrepo then display all its data. After that you can remove children from you router config.

Comment: is there any way i can manually add the repoName to the url as a child with this way?

Comment: You dont need do this, repo is stored in component so you dont need its name in url.

Comment: right, well i wanted it so that users could go directly to the url and it would have the repo already open for them